# Create a background service in android remotely

Tags: android, service

I want to create a service whose function will not be known forehand. When the app is started, the function (which is decided at run time) to be performed is sent from the server to the mobile.

For example, when the app runs server may ask to list all installed apps in the mobile and app replies. When developing the app we dont know that server is going to ask for installed apps. App should be able to respond to any command from the server.

Android app acts like a client to all commands from the server.

Comment: I dont understand, just check the response from the server then do whatever method it ask you to do and send it back

Comment: do you want to do something like a reflection? But, can you mention more details and be specific?

Comment: Problem is server can send any command to the app. Quoting the example, when developing the app we dont know that sever is going to ask to list all installed apps. App should be able to do any task from the server.

Comment: if you dont know what the server is going to send how would your app know what to do or if it can even do it?

Answer (score 0):

Apply the push notification, while on receive the notification, start your service with the tasks sent by the server.

Comment: Problem is server can send any command to the app. Quoting the example, when developing the app we dont know that sever is going to ask to list all installed apps. App should be able to do any task from the server.

Comment: tasks should be predefined, unless how you can serve it. Let take an example, server asked for the wifi signal strength, how would app serves this if app doesn't have the required permissions and system service manager? Ask yourself before implementing.